# Can I ask Allah to grant me a fictional character as my wife in Jannah?

Tags: allah, jannah, creation

Well this may seem pretty childish to many, but I just want a direct answer.

I am very obsessed with this fictional character in a book I used to read as a child, this fictional female character (Which I will not name) has every quality that I find ideal in an intimate way and can relate to. But sadly, fantasies are just that fantasies.

I’ve had relationships in my life before, but never have I found a woman with the qualities that are suitable for me, Even though, I have committed Zina before (not physically) I repented to Allah (swt).

I have decided to quit on getting married in my life since I just don’t want to get married to reproduce and I’m sure my hypothetical future wife would not be with happy with me.

I was just sitting in work today and just had that random thought that piqued my interest a bit and got me kind of excited so I had to ask.

Let’s say judgement day has passed and the people of Jannah and Jahannam have parted ways and ***inshallah i enter Jannah,*** then if I ask Allah (swt) to bring that fictional being who was only a creation of someone else’s mind to life, **will** **my wish be granted?**

Answer (score 2):

My brother in Islam, you are not the only one who has fallen in love with a fictional character. . During Ramadan 2017, I've had worries about the character I love being in Jannah, and I went on a wild goose chase for answers, and alhamdullillah, I've found a Hadith.

Once the Prophet (sallallaahu `alayhi wasallam) was narrating (a story), while a Bedouin was sitting with him. “One of the inhabitants of Paradise will ask Allah to allow him to cultivate the land. Allah will ask him, ‘Are you not living in the pleasures you like?’ He will say, ‘Yes, but I like to cultivate the land.’ ” The Prophet (sallallaahu`alayhi wasallam) added, “When the man (will be permitted he) will sow the seeds and the plants will grow up and get ripe, ready for reaping and so on till it will be as huge as mountains within a wink. Allah will then say to him, ‘O son of Adam! Take here you are, gather (the yield); nothing satisfies you.’ ” On that, the bedouin said, “The man must be either from Quraish (i.e. an emigrant) or an Ansari, for they are farmers, whereas we are not farmers.” The Prophet (sallallaahu `alayhi wasallam) smiled (at this).

What this means brother, is that the worldly desires we have now will be fulfilled in Jannah. This man loved planting in his life, and in Jannah, he remembered what he loved, asked Allah Almighty for it, and got it. Planting is described in the Qur'an as a worldly pleasure. So let's put that in perspective. We love fictional women, or fictional females, and want to have them come to life in Jannah, to be our wives or partners. Brother, you're in luck, because the Hadith I just mentioned is an example of someone loving something from this world, going to Jannah, remembering his desire, and desiring it. Just think about it. Allah Almighty will satisfy you until you want nothing more, until you are so happy, you feel like the luckiest man alive. But remember, in order to attain that, we have to live according to the teachings of Islam, because that is the only way to Jannah.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, in Jannah? Or now? Well, if it's in jannah, it has rewards beyond your fantasies and your imagination.. Allah mentioned that in jannah, they will get whatever they wish for.. So you should be occupied with how to get to jannah.. 
As for now, you can ask Allah to give you peace and happiness and to guide you to please him and to enter jannah.. And Allah knows what's in your heart and your desires, if you ask sincerely, who knows, maybe Allah will send you someone similar to that character or change your heart and make you fall in love with someone else and laugh at your current fantasy..

Answer (score 1):

You can never achieve jannah, by living your life according to the fantasies in world. So you have to stick to your actual purpose of life (live life exactly according to Quran and Sunnah And reject every haram action), then hope that Allah may send you to jannah.

Once you active jannah, then as we will get all our wishes fulfilled, then you might get what you want (fictional woman) But for that,you have to pass the exam of this life. as to live all this life according to Quran and Sunnah. get married. have intimate relatiinship with your wife, and produce children.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is YES. Allah will give you what you want in Jannah if you make it there. It is mentioned in the Qur'an. But bear in mind that the creations in Heaven are way more glorious than the most glorious and beautiful creations of our imagination.
Just be hopeful and focus on getting to Jannah by walking on righ path. InchAllah it will all be worth it in the end.